# Hibernate: delete related rows

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table HEAD and a table DETAIL with a relation one-to-many.
In java class Head relation is mapped like this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "sdId")
private Collection<Detail> detailCollection;
```

What i need to do is delete every row related with a specific Head:

```
Head head=getCurrentHead();
deleteDetails(head);
```

what is the best way to implement deleteDetails()?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since the cascade type is `Cascade.ALL`, just clear the collection:

```
if (<condition>) {
    head.getDetailCollection().clear();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Luiggi  but i have this exception trying to clear collection:

`org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: it.dhl.wla.common.data.beans.Head.detailCollection, no session or session was closed`

(I'm new with Hibernate and this code is not mine)

Comment: It means your object is outside a proper hibernate Session. I don't know how you're managing sessions, but basically you have to: 1) open a new session, 2) refresh the `head` object in the session, 3) clear the collection, 4) close the session (after commiting the changes); or, on the other hand, maintain the session alive while this method is called.

Comment: I have a method getCurrentHead() that gives me an Head instance. It open and close a session, so you are right: session is closed when later i try to clear collection.
Should i get again my Head instance from database?
like this:
`
- get a session
- get the head instance from db
- clear collection
- close session
`

Comment: Thank you very much @Luiggi!

I hope that overhead in this situation is managed by internal cache?

Comment: It will be handled by First level cache.